# Change permissions on heaps of announcement lists in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have heaps of announcement lists in sites and subsites and I need to change permission levels so that on these list users with Contribute permissions cannot add a new announcement. I can't remove add from the level permission as they need to be able to add various things to other lists/pages.

Is there a powershell command to get all announcement lists and set that Contribute cannot add?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try SharePoint Permission Batch?   http://www.sharepointboost.com/batchpermission.html

Comment: Not for 500 bucks!  I doubt a free trial is full-featured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot alter the permission level just for each of those lists like that. You'll need to break permission inheritiance on each list (presuming subsites are all inheriting permissions from the root already) and remove the contribute permission level from the salient groups, and replace it with the "reader" permission level instead.